# How do I change the splash screen in the Intel XDK?

Tags: html, splash-screen, intel-xdk

I am creating a HTML5 app using the Intel XDK and I want to change the splash screen from the default Project Development. How do I do this?

If this is not possible then how do I remove the splash screen?

Answer (score 9):

- When you ready to build your app. Make change splash screen in **Build**=>**Assets** Tabs

See picture below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/alBEQ.png]

- To remove splash screen, just comment out the line:

  ```
  var onDeviceReady=function(){
  ...
  //hide splash screen
  //**intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();**  
  };
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the updated answer hope this is helpful.
[image: Change intel xdk spalash screen]

Answer (score 0):

when you are building the app for ios/android..., you can select splash screen and icons for your app, upload there and build.

http://appcenter.html5tools-software.intel.com/

Comment: Provided link is broken. Or at least it doesn't lead to any page with information specific to splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

Add a splashscreen to your app by creating a div in the afui div and setting the id to "splashscreen". When af.ui.launch is called, it will remove the splashscreen from the DOM.

```
<div id="afui">
    <div id="splashscreen" class='ui-loader'>
        <img src="kitchensink/images/splash.png">
        <br><br>
        <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading spin'></span><h1 >Starting app</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Remember, this will only be visible until $.ui.launch finishes, so to it display longer disable auto launch by setting $.ui.autoLaunch to false and triggering the launch later using $.ui.launch().

Reference: http://app-framework-software.intel.com/documentation.php#tips/tips_splashscreen

Hope this help ;)